# Haskell | How to obtain a value from a deeply nested data structure?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, haskell-lens, lenses

I am a beginner in haskell and I'm trying to learn more about the language by doing some basic parsing.

I have some code that parses an XML file and produces this

```
[ Element
    { elName = QName
        { qName = "title"
        , qURI = Nothing
        , qPrefix = Nothing
        }
    , elAttribs = []
    , elContent =
        [ Text
            ( CData
                { cdVerbatim = CDataText
                , cdData = "This string is what I want to obtain" -- string to view.
                , cdLine = Just 27
                }
            )
        ]
    , elLine = Just 27
    }
]
```

Where `Element` is just a [XML library's](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-1.3.14/docs/Text-XML-Light-Types.html#t:Element) data type

What I want to do is get the string `"This string is what I want to obtain"`

I'm not sure how to do it without unwrapping the entire data structure. I found that way really messy and error prone.

I did some general research and found the [Lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library, and although there were some tutorials, I'm still struggling to parse a nested data structure.

This is the XML file I'm trying to parse looks

```
<GoodreadsResponse>
    <Request>
        <authentication>true</authentication>
        <key>HOKCk4yYS8UjyducqmgRw</key>
        <method>search_search</method>
    </Request>
    <search>
        <query>fantasy</query>
        <results-start>1</results-start>
        <results-end>20</results-end>
        <total-results>35221</total-results>
        <source>Goodreads</source>
        <query-time-seconds>0.21</query-time-seconds>
        <results>
            <work>
                <id type="integer">2384</id>
                <books_count type="integer">51</books_count>
                <ratings_count type="integer">78825</ratings_count>
                <text_reviews_count type="integer">3357</text_reviews_count>
                <original_publication_year type="integer">2002</original_publication_year>
                <original_publication_month type="integer">2</original_publication_month>
                <original_publication_day type="integer">18</original_publication_day>
                <average_rating>4.17</average_rating>
                <best_book type="Book">
                    <id type="integer">84136</id>
                    <title>Fantasy Lover (Hunter Legends Series #1)</title>
                    <author>
                        <id type="integer">4430</id>
                        <name>Sherrilyn Kenyon</name>
                    </author>
                    <image_url>https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1348332807m/84136.jpg</image_url>
                    <small_image_url>https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1348332807s/84136.jpg</small_image_url>
                </best_book>
            </work>
            <work>
                <id type="integer">6734901</id>
                <books_count type="integer">42</books_count>
                <ratings_count type="integer">18358</ratings_count>
                <text_reviews_count type="integer">985</text_reviews_count>
                <original_publication_year type="integer">2010</original_publication_year>
                <original_publication_month type="integer" nil="true"/>
                <original_publication_day type="integer" nil="true"/>
                <average_rating>4.26</average_rating>
                <best_book type="Book">
                    <id type="integer">6542645</id>
                    <title>Fantasy in Death (In Death, #30)</title>
                    <author>
                        <id type="integer">17065</id>
                        <name>J.D. Robb</name>
                    </author>
                    <image_url>https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/book/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png</image_url>
                    <small_image_url>https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/book/50x75-a91bf249278a81aabab721ef782c4a74.png</small_image_url>
                </best_book>
            </work>
       ...
       ...
```

Comment: Maybe you could tell us a bit more about your use-case. The `xml` package is very lightweight, but also very bare-bones. Maybe it's a good fit for you together with lenses, but maybe you would also better use another xml parsing library.

Comment: I'm trying to parse XML response from Goodreads API. The request URL gives user a list of books with its title, author, book id, etc. Books from a specific genre. The response can be 10 fields per page. This is the request URL `https://www.goodreads.com/search.xml?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&q=fiction`

Comment: @mb21 I've added a sample of the xml file I'm trying to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehensions and record accessors is fairly clear:

```
get :: [Element] -> [String]
get es = [cdData c | e <- es, Text c <- elContent e ]
```

The `Text c` pattern will automatically filter out any `Elem e` or `CRef s` values in `elContent e`.

Once you learn that, for lists, `=<<` means `concatMap`, you can save a few characters with

```
get :: [Element] -> [String]
get es = [cdData c | Text c <- elContent =<< es]
```

Additionaly, if you only wanted the `cdData` when the `cdVerbatim` was `CDataText`, you can add that condition.

```
get :: [Element] -> [String]
get es = [cdData c | Text c <- elContent =<< es, cdVerbatim c == CDataText ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `xml` doesn't defined any optics itself, you'll need another package which does. @Li-yaoXia found one: [`lens-xml`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-xml).

```
 #!/usr/bin/env cabal
 {- cabal:
 build-depends: base
              , xml
              , lens
              , lens-xml
 -}
 {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

 import Control.Lens
 import Text.XML.Light.Types
 import Text.XML.Light.Lens

 x = [ Element
         { elName = QName
             { qName = "title"
             , qURI = Nothing
             , qPrefix = Nothing
             }
         , elAttribs = []
         , elContent =
             [ Text
                 ( CData
                     { cdVerbatim = CDataText
                     , cdData = "This string is what I want to obtain" -- string to view.
                     , cdLine = Just 27
                     }
                 )
             ]
         , elLine = Just 27
         }
     ]

 main :: IO ()
 main = print (x ^? ix 0 . elContentL . ix 0 . _Text . cdDataL)
```

You can run this with a recent version of `cabal`:

```
$ cabal new-run Main.hs
<<lots of build output snipped>>
Just "This string is what I want to obtain"
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm not sure I would agree with the idea of using `lens` for this task. Personally, I'd lean towards first converting the XML into a data type (with error messages when the XML doesn't fit the expected schema), then working over that data type. However, you did ask for a `lens` based solution...

Comment: There is `lens-xml`

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Thanks!

Comment: @Alec Thanks for the answer and the suggestion! Parsing XML into Haskell datatypes was my first idea but looking around I didn't see any concrete examples or tutorials going over it. Many were using `Arrows`, others combinators which I felt were too complex for me at the moment. Although if it's indeed possible to convert XML into Haskell data types easily (which can be understood by a beginner), something like how `aeson` parses `JSON` files, I can post another question.